# spark taking more space while caching hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am caching one of my HIVE table which is stored in parquet format on HDFS. Size of my HIVE table is around 3.5G.

I am reading HIVE table into Spark DataFrame and caching the same, but it is taking around 24G of Memory when I checked in Spark UI.

Could anyone please help me to understand this difference in size. Why it is taking more spark in Spark.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: is your stored parquet file compressed?

Comment: How I can check if the parquet file is compressed or not.

Comment: compressed files look like:         file.gz.parquet  or file.snappy.parquet 
in general its:                             file.[compression].parquet
uncompressed files look like:     file.parquet

Comment: Its in compressed format like file.gz.parquet

Comment: then there's your answer :) If you uncompress the file it will likely be in the 2-10X range larger than it was compressed

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Got it.